# Cannot use https (secure connection) on Firefox

Tags: firefox, ssl, https

Suddenly I cannot access any `https` connection. Firefox shows an error

```
Error code: ssl_error_rx_record_too_long
```

Even I cannot access Google (http). It shows blank page most of the time. I did not do anything at all. I Googled about `ssl` error but all indicated apache2 virtual-host fact. But I don't have apache installed in my system. I did not change any kind of config file. So why is it happening?

I am using a modem (with WiFi router facilities). Other computers in this network are working just fine. I am using 12.04 64bit. System date is okay (synchronize with time server).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that port 443 is open and enabled on your server. This is the standard port for https communications.

If this doesn't solve your problem its better to connect to [Firefox support](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions)

I've seen there problems like this but only for specific website and the solution was to remove some Addons so its better to tell them your peoblem in details if my answer doesn't help you

Comment: It is not firefox's problem.Same problem for chrome and chromium-browser. I am not running any server and do not use any proxy. How do i check open port?

Comment: `iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --sport 443 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT`                   This command will open this port

Comment: It's the port for the secure connection

Comment: @IZX ---  By default, HTTP uses port 80 and HTTPS uses port 443

Comment: The one downvoted I need to know Why?!!!

Comment: When you make an HTTPS connection, the local source port is usually random 1024-65535, while the **destination port** on the remote server is 443. Opening or closing local 443 isn't going to make a difference.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_%28computer_networking%29

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Secure

Comment: http://www.rebol.com/docs/ssl.html   http://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xml   http://www.grc.com/port_443.htm   http://www.chebucto.ns.ca/~rakerman/port-table.html   http://www.webopedia.com/quick_ref/portnumbers.asp

Comment: All those and million of other links state that port 443 is the port of https and it use it in source host

Comment: Yes, 443 is the port ON THE SERVER; the OP here has a problem WITH THE CLIENT.